# How can I change the “Privacy & Terms” link in new No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA from google

Tags: recaptcha

how can i change or hide Privacy & Terms link in google  new reCAPTCHA.
i try with css and jquery both are not working
EX

```
$('.rc-anchor-privacy').hide()
```